# Webview blank page shown in Nougat OS in my app

Tags: android, android-webview, payment-gateway, android-7.0-nougat, ccavenue

I have called CCAvenue Payment Gateway Integration in my app. till it is working properly but when i update my device OS Marshmallow to Nougat, Webview page display blank white screen.

No Error log found in logcat also.

I have also tested in all another device which lower than Nougat and in that devices, WebView working properly. Only issue found in Nougat OS.

I have searched this issue in google, but not found any proper solution from last three days.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#webview. try changing "You can choose your WebView provider by enabling Developer Options and selecting WebView implementation. You can use any compatible Chrome version (Dev, Beta or Stable) that is installed on your device or the standalone Webview APK to act as the WebView implementation. "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, when I update my android device from marshmallow to Nougat,
I found on my updated device, android Webview system app is permanent disabled and Nougat OS uses Chrome browser's Webview by default as define in this
[link.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#webview)

And My device already installed old chrome browser does not rendering this webview. when I update my Chrome browser app than its working fine in all webview pages.

Comment: i have also same problem and fixed updating chrome

Comment: Have a medal, sir. Hell, have two.

Comment: Hello Sir, I have use Google pixel. i have face same problem and as per your comment i have update my crome app but still same issue face. Please reply me any other solution. thank you in advance.