# WebView shows blank white page since Android 7

Tags: java, android, webview

The code below works well on devices prior to Android 7. With Android 7 and 8 `WebView` shows empty white screen instead of some content:

**java part:**

```
public static class QuickIntroFragment1 extends Fragment{
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_web_view, container, false);
            WebView wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wv_intro);
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/learn_methodology.html");
            return view;
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest already contains necessary permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Local `html` part below, but other urls (e.g. google.com) also not showing :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Word Dolphin documentation</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      ul{
      margin-left:-17px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Language learning consists of several parts: skill of creating and understanding of sentences, vocabulary filling, pronunciation training and communication skills. Word Dolphin helps to learn words and prevent to forget it.</p>
<ul>
    <li>if you want to come to a mutual understanding you need to know about 3000 words. 7-9  thousand words will be sufficient for everyday communication. Where to get these words? Firstly, you can search by phrases similar to "1000 most popular words". Secondly, just read in the learning language. Preferably, these texts on the well-known theme. So, except the most popular words, you obtain living language samples.</li>
    <li>after you have found the unknown word, add it to WordDolphin and define translation. In fact, there may be a lot of meanings of the word. But you should learn 3 or 4 most used meanings. Learn it. Optimal quantity is 2 or 3 meanings because more will be difficult to remember. For many languages, Google or Microsoft Translator shows the most used meanings, pronunciation samples, etc.</li>
    <li>after you have added unknown words with translations, you can remember them. First learn few words, for example 5, and step by step increase its quantity. The main rule here: they should be easy to remember. It is necessary to listen to pronunciation and try to repeat it. Very good practice to remember words is writing.</li>
    <li>finally, check the meaning. It is necessary because learned words will be forgotten fast without practice. Firstly repeat newly learned words, then the rest. Word Dolphin keeps up your skills and based on it will create checklist.</li>
</ul>
<p>For read more tap ☰ and select <b>Info</b>.</p>
<p>Good work!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This behavior appear on Google Android Emulator. So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613342/webview-blank-page-shown-in-nougat-os-in-my-app) not my problem.

Comment: @AmitVaghela No, I use Google Android emulator

Comment: update that to questions.

Comment: @AmitVaghela I have updated my post

Comment: can you please update HTML page as per my observation there is no start of body tag and try.  <body>

Comment: @DamodharMeshram see updated `html`

Comment: but `html` gets loaded from storage?

Comment: @sschrass I will check it

Comment: can we used android_assets?. as per below comment there is some problem with raw :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027701/loading-existing-html-file-with-android-webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is problems with my hardware because with more powerful hardware and the same emulated image I don't observe this bug.